# iText -> Best approach to read XMP metadata?

Tags: java, itext, xmp

It appears that in 5.5.2 of iText the XmpReader is deprecated along with a lot of other things related to XMP.

What is the recommended to reading XMP metadata from Pdf files?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the [changelog from 5.4.4](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/544) you'll find:

> - **Changes made by Eugene Markovskyi**
>
>   - Replaced the iText XMP implementation with Adobe's XMP Core library

You'll want to look into the [`com.itextpdf.xmp`](http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/itext/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/xmp/) namespace and you're probably most interested in [`XmpMetaFactory.parseFromBuffer`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/xmp/XMPMetaFactory.html#parseFromBuffer(byte[])) which you can pass the metadata from `PdfReader` to.